# Yasnippet including backslash

Tags: regular-expressions, yasnippet, backslash

I would like to use Yasnippet to insert the template for a latex inline equation: `\( \)`

The snippet is defined:

```
    # -*- Mode: snippet -*-
# name: inline equation
# key: ineq
# --
\(  \)
```

But Yasnippet inserts only the parentheses `( )` without the backslashes. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash with another backslash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) is used in regular expressions to escape individual characters:

> For the most part, `\` followed by any character matches only that character.

So `\(` gives you `(` in your output.  To get the backslash in the output, escape it:

```
\\( \\)
```

Comment: http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3 would be a better link, this isn't about regular expressions.